# How do I negate a set of characters together in a Regular Expression? Ex: [^<\/a>] (When you find </a> stop matching)

Tags: php, regex

How do I negate a set of characters together in Regular Expression? Ex: [^</a>] (When you find  stop matching)
when I do this way the code stops when it finds an "a" in the text

How do I do to negate a set of characters

This is the expression:

```
$string = "<a href='asdasd'>lalalala</a>";
preg_match('/<a href=.*?>([^<\/a>]+)/',$string,$res);
```

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simpler alternative to an assertion one could just match text content, stop at tag delimiters:

```
 preg_match('/<a href=.*?>([^<>]+)/', $string, $res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use negative lookahead:

```
.(?!</a>)
```

will match any character not followed by `</a>`.

Thus, to match a whole string that doesn't contain `</a>`:

```
^(.(?!</a>))*$
```